# Como separar funções/variáveis globais do programa em arquivos?

Tags: c, arquivo, include

Tenho alguns arquivos:

```
vetores.c // função main
uniao.c // função para unir vetores
ordena.c // função para ordenar vetores
globais.c // arquivo com variáveis globais
```

Quero saber como eu referencio um arquivo no outro.

**Exemplo:** preciso usar as variáveis de `globais.c` no `vetores.c`, assim como chamar as funções de `ordena.c` e `uniao.c` no `vetores.c`, e as funções de `ordena.c` em `uniao.c` e outros... Tentei usando arquivos *headers* (`.h`) assim:

**globais.h**

```
#ifndef _GLOBAIS_H_
#define _GLOBAIS_H_

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *A, *B, ta, tb;
#endif
```

**ordena.h**

```
#ifndef _ORDENA_H_
#define _ORDENA_H_

int* ordena(int *vet, int tam);

#endif
```

**uniao.h**

```
#ifndef _UNIAO_H_
#define _UNIAO_H_

int* uniao( int *vet1, int tam1, int *vet2, int tam2);

#endif
```

E nos arquivos `.c` usei referências assim:

```
#include"uniao.h"
#include"globais.h"
#include"ordena.h"
```

Tentei também direto pelo `.c`:

```
#include"uniao.c"
#include"globais.c"
#include"ordena.c"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O pouco do código mostrado indica claramente que não deve haver essa separação. Aparentemente todo o código tem uma relação direta e é importante que ele esteja junto. Uma separação só deve ocorrer se houver um motivo para isso, precisa ter uma funcionalidade à parte, o que não ocorre nesse caso.

O arquivo deve funcionar como uma unidade lógica. Ele funciona, bem grosso modo, como é uma classe nas linguagens orientadas a objeto. Só pode estar ali o que tem relação direta com aquilo e tudo que tem relação direta deve estar só ali e não em outros lugares.

O problema é maior ainda quando se usa variáveis globais. Deveria se evitar isso, mas já que usou aumenta o motivo para estar tudo junto.

Arquivos *header* só devem existir para declarar elementos que serão usados em outros contextos. Se tudo estiver em um arquivo só, não tem porque existir.

Eles foram inventados para solucionar um problema de organização e não para usar sem ter um motivo. Ele só deve ser usado se encontrar uma boa justificativa para seu uso.

Pode ser interessante separar é o `main()`, mas depende de entender um contexto mais amplo, neste caso, eu duvido. E se for para separar aí o *header* das outras funções seria útil. Reforço que não parece ser o caso.

Outro ponto que não se deve fazer é incluir um `#include` dentro do outro para que seja inserido no código `.c`. O `#include` deve ser usado no arquivo onde ele é necessário, não se deve delegar sua inclusão para outros arquivos, isto acaba provocando um caos em projetos maiores.

Mesmo que a intenção seja aprender a fazer a separação, nesse caso, o melhor é não fazer isto. E se for para simular precisaria ter acesso a todo o código para ver o que deve estar em cada arquivo. Sem ver tudo e saber quais os problemas nem dá para responder mais que isto.

O ideal é ir pelo caminho mais simples e fazer aquilo que se domina.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela explicação, era realmente para quesitos educacionais, apenas para entender como funciona isso etc, estou mais acostumado com outras linguagens. As globais foram criadas apenas para fazer essa separação, pois futuramente eu precisaria indica-las em vários lugares (o programa ira crescer ainda), vou retorna-las como locais.

Comment: Aí é que tá, quanto mais o programa cresce, menos deve usar variáveis globais. Na verdade o ideal é que elas não existam em programas. Eu até entendo a motivação, porém não adianta fazer algo errado para aprender o conceito certo. Se tiver um contexto melhor, onde a separação é natural e necessária, fica mais fácil mostrar como. Fora isto, está tudo certo no código, deveria funcionar (claro que não vi o resto).

Comment: Na realidade as variáveis globais nem precisariam existir nesse caso, só usar ponteiro.. Obrigado aí.

Comment: Sim, dá para evitar variáveis globais em 100% do casos.

Comment: No caso lá dos arquivos, analisei e consegui ver o problema, estava incluindo .h em lugares errados, fiz o seguinte: Declarei o somente o .h com o mesmo nome no .c e todos .h no main, outro erro era no união.h não ter incluído o orneda.h.. Entendi como funciona.